# Check 3 Integers to see if they are Fibonacci triple

Tags: python, fibonacci

I am trying to input 3 integers and determine if they are Fibonacci Triples. A Fibonacci Triple is three consecutive Fibonacci numbers. Can someone help me figure out where I'm going wrong. Thanks!

```
def fibs():
    a, b = 0, 1
    yield a
    yield b
    while True:
      a,b = b, a + b
      yield b

fibInput = (input("please enter 3 numbers separated by commas: "))
n, o, p = [int(i) for i in fibInput.split(',')]
#print(n,o,p) TEST

for fib in fibs():
    if n == fib and o == fib and p == fib:
        print("Your numbers are a fibonacci triple.")
        break
    if fib > n and fib > o and fib > p:
        print("your numbers are not a fibonacci triple.")
        break
```

Comment: you should sort the input in order to have n<o<p. Then, when you have reach fib==n, you check the next fib (==o?), and then the next one (==p?).

Comment: I'm new to Python. As far as sorting, Im assuming I would use the sort function but i'm lost beyond that

Comment: Well the first check would be that the largest is the sum of the two smaller numbers, otherwise they are definitely not a triple

Answer (score 0):

```
if n == fib and o == fib and p == fib:
```

You're not checking whether the three numbers are consecutive Fibonacci numbers. You're checking whether they're all the **same** Fibonacci number.

Comment: any suggestions? Now i know i need more variables; just unsure as to how to go about creating such to accomplish this task

Answer (score 0):

In your loop `fib` has the same value.

You could write other generator for Fibonacci triples

```
def fib_triple():
    it = iter(fibs())
    a = it.next()
    b = it.next()
    c = it.next()
    while True:
        yield(a, b, c)
        a, b, c = b, c, it.next()
```